# Split strings into smaller ones to create new rows in a data frame (in R)

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I'm a newish R user and I'm currently struggling with how to split strings in each row of a data frame and then create a new row with the modified string (along with modifying the original). This is an example below but the actual data set is much bigger.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
library(utils)

posts_sentences <- data.frame("element_id" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), "sentence_id" = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3), 
                "sentence" = c("You know, when I grew up, I grew up in a very religious family, I had the same sought of troubles people have, I was excelling in alot of ways, but because there was alot of trouble at home, we were always moving around", "Im at breaking point.I have no one to talk to about this and if I’m honest I think I’m too scared to tell anyone because if I do then it becomes real.I dont know what to do.", "I feel like I’m going to explode.", "I have so many thoughts and feelings inside and I don't know who to tell and I was going to tell my friend about it but I'm not sure.", "I keep saying omg!it's too much"), 
                "sentence_wc" = c(60, 30, 7, 20, 7), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I want to break up the sentences that are above a certain word count (15 for this data set), create new sentences from within the longer sentences using regex so that first I try to break it up by periods (or other symbols), then if the word count is still too long, I try commas followed by an I (or capital letter) and then I try 'and' followed by a capital letter, etc. Every time I create a new sentence, it needs to change the sentence from the old row to just the first part of the sentence along with changing the word count (I have a function for this) along with creating a new row with the same element id, a sentence id that comes next the sequence (if sentence_id was 1, now new sentence is 2), the new sentence word count and then changing all the below sentences to be the next sentence_id number.

I have been working on this for a few days and can't figure out how to do it. I've tried using unnest tokens, str_split/extract and various dplyr combinations of filter, mutate, etc along with google/SO searches. Does anyone know of the best way to accomplish this? Dplyr is preferred but I'm open to anything that works. Feel free to ask questions if you need any clarification!

Edit to add the expected output data frame:

```
expected_output <- data.frame("element_id" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), "sentence_id" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                                   "sentence" = c("You know, when I grew up", "I grew up in a very religious family", "I had the same sought of troubles people have", "I was excelling in alot of ways, but because there was alot of trouble at home, we were always moving around", "Im at breaking point.", "I have no one to talk to about this and if I’m honest I think I’m too scared to tell anyone because if I do then it becomes real.", "I dont know what to do.", "I feel like I’m going to explode.", "I have so many thoughts and feelings inside and", "I don't know who to tell and", "I was going to tell my friend about it but I'm not sure.", "I keep saying omg!", "it's too much"), 
                                   "sentence_wc" = c(6, 8, 8, 21, 4, 27, 6, 7, 9, 7, 13, 4, 3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: @akrun I just did, thanks for the reminder! Not sure how to do it where you can actually see the table like I've seen in other questions.

Comment: Your `expected_output` has two rows with `sentence_wc > 15`.  Why do those lines not get broken down further?  Also, can you provide your actual regex?  "Periods (or other symbols)" is too vague, especially if commas are not considered until the second set ("commas followed by an...").  What counts as "other symbols"?

Comment: Is there a character limit in addition to word limit?

Comment: @andrew_reece The sentence word count doesn't really matter, it's just there to check if the sentence needs to be broken down in the next split. If nothing works, it will remain as it is or will get broken down by number of words (I already know how to do this). I am not sure of what exactly regex will be used (work in progress) but here is an initial example of possible symbols that could be included before or after the commas:

"[^\\s!…?/;_\\[\\]\\*\\.&:(),\"-]+"

Comment: @Chris No character limit, just word limit. The number of words affects later calculations.

Comment: Your expected output still has sentences with more than 15 words? do you have a heuristic to break them down further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach that allows you to specify your own heuristics, which I think should be the best for your situation. The key is the use of `pmap` to create lists of each row that you can then split if necessary with `map_if`. This is a situation that is hard to do with `dplyr` alone in my opinion, because we're adding rows in our operation and so `rowwise` is hard to use.

The structure of `split_too_long()` is basically:

1. Use `dplyr::mutate` and `tokenizers::count_words` to get the word count of each sentence
2. make each row an element of a list with `purrr::pmap`, which accepts the dataframe as a list of columns as input
3. use `purrr::map_if` to check if the word count is greater than our desired limit
4. use `tidyr::separate_rows` to split the sentence into multiple rows if the above condition is met,
5. then replace the word count with the new word count and drop any empty rows with `filter` (created by doubled up separators).

We can then apply this for different separators as we realise that the elements need to be split further. Here I use these patterns corresponding to the heuristics you mention:

- `"[\\.\\?\\!] ?"` which matches any of `.!?` and an optional space
- `", ?(?=[:upper:])"` which matches `,`, optional space, preceding an uppercase letter
- `"and ?(?=[:upper:])"` which matches `and` optional space, preceding an uppercase letter.

It correctly returns the same split sentences as in your expected output. The `sentence_id` is easy to add back in at the end with `row_number`, and errant leading/trailing whitespace can be removed with `stringr::str_trim`.

Caveats:

- I wrote this for readability in exploratory analysis, hence splitting into the lists and binding back together each time. If you decide in advance what separators you want you can put it into one `map` step which would probably make it faster, though I haven't profiled this on a large dataset.
- As per comments, there are still sentences with more than 15 words after these splits. You will have to decide what additional symbols/regular expressions you want to split on to get the lengths down more.
- The column names are hardcoded into `split_too_long` at present. I recommend you look into the `programming with dplyr` vignette if being able to specify column names in the call to the function is important to you (it should only be a few tweaks to achieve it)

```r
posts_sentences <- data.frame(
  "element_id" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), "sentence_id" = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3),
  "sentence" = c("You know, when I grew up, I grew up in a very religious family, I had the same sought of troubles people have, I was excelling in alot of ways, but because there was alot of trouble at home, we were always moving around", "Im at breaking point.I have no one to talk to about this and if I’m honest I think I’m too scared to tell anyone because if I do then it becomes real.I dont know what to do.", "I feel like I’m going to explode.", "I have so many thoughts and feelings inside and I don't know who to tell and I was going to tell my friend about it but I'm not sure.", "I keep saying omg!it's too much"),
  "sentence_wc" = c(60, 30, 7, 20, 7), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(tidyverse)
library(tokenizers)
split_too_long <- function(df, regexp, max_length) {
  df %>%
    mutate(wc = count_words(sentence)) %>%
    pmap(function(...) tibble(...)) %>%
    map_if(
      .p = ~ .$wc > max_length,
      .f = ~ separate_rows(., sentence, sep = regexp)
      ) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    mutate(wc = count_words(sentence)) %>%
    filter(wc != 0)
}

posts_sentences %>%
  group_by(element_id) %>%
  summarise(sentence = str_c(sentence, collapse = ".")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  split_too_long("[\\.\\?\\!] ?", 15) %>%
  split_too_long(", ?(?=[:upper:])", 15) %>%
  split_too_long("and ?(?=[:upper:])", 15) %>%
  group_by(element_id) %>%
  mutate(
    sentence = str_trim(sentence),
    sentence_id = row_number()
  ) %>%
  select(element_id, sentence_id, sentence, wc)
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#> # Groups:   element_id [2]
#>    element_id sentence_id sentence                                      wc
#>         <dbl>       <int> <chr>                                      <int>
#>  1          1           1 You know, when I grew up                       6
#>  2          1           2 I grew up in a very religious family           8
#>  3          1           3 I had the same sought of troubles people ~     9
#>  4          1           4 I was excelling in alot of ways, but beca~    21
#>  5          1           5 Im at breaking point                           4
#>  6          1           6 I have no one to talk to about this and i~    29
#>  7          1           7 I dont know what to do                         6
#>  8          2           1 I feel like I’m going to explode               7
#>  9          2           2 I have so many thoughts and feelings insi~     8
#> 10          2           3 I don't know who to tell                       6
#> 11          2           4 I was going to tell my friend about it bu~    13
#> 12          2           5 I keep saying omg                              4
#> 13          2           6 it's too much                                  3
```

Created on 2018-05-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for this long and detailed answer, it is super helpful. However when I run it on my computer with the above sample data, I get this error:

`Error in captureDots(strict =  __quosured ) : 
  the argument has already been evaluated 
26.
captureDots(strict =  __quosured ) 
25.
dots_capture(...,  __interp_lhs  =  __interp_lhs ) 
24.
dots_enquose(...) 
23.
quos(..., .named = TRUE) 
22.
tibble(...) at sample_dataset.R#35
21.
.f(element_id = .l[[c(1L, i)]], sentence = .l[[c(2L, i)]], wc = .l[[c(3L, 
    i)]], ...)`

Do you have any idea why that error occurs?

Comment: I don't know, would check all your package versions as well as your R version. You may need to update your tidyverse packages, as well as rlang

Comment: For reference, i have R 3.5.0, tidyverse 1.2.1, and rlang 0.2.0.9001 from github, though i would expect the release version to work

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I updated the R version to 3.5.0 (I think this was the issue) and the packages and now it works. I really appreciate the time you took to help me with this!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I have edited the whole answer to address the specific problem in more detail.

This isn't entirely generic because it assumes the groups are made solely based on `element_id`.

```
split_too_long <- function(str, max.words=15L, ...) {
  cuts <- stringi::stri_locate_all_words(str)[[1L]]

  # return one of these
  if (nrow(cuts) <= max.words) {
    c(str, NA_character_)
  }
  else {
    left <- substr(str, 1L, cuts[max.words, 2L])
    right <- substr(str, cuts[max.words + 1L, 1L], nchar(str))
    c(left, right)
  }
}

recursive_split <- function(not_done, done=NULL, ...) {
  left_right <- split_too_long(not_done, ...)

  # return one of these
  if (is.na(left_right[2L]))
    c(done, left_right[1L])
  else
    recursive_split(left_right[2L], done=c(done, left_right[1L]), ...)
}

collapse_split <- function(sentences, regex="[.;:] ?", ...) {
  sentences <- paste(sentences, collapse=". ")
  sentences <- unlist(strsplit(sentences, split=regex))
  # return
  unlist(lapply(sentences, recursive_split, done=NULL, ...))
}

group_fun <- function(grouped_df, ...) {
  # initialize new data frame with new number of rows
  new_df <- data.frame(sentence=collapse_split(grouped_df$sentence, ...),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  # count words
  new_df$sentence_wc <- stringi::stri_count_words(new_df$sentence)
  # add sentence_id
  new_df$sentence_id <- 1L:nrow(new_df)
  # element_id must be equal because it is a grouping variable,
  # so take 1 to repeat it in output
  new_df$element_id <- grouped_df$element_id[1L]
  # return
  dplyr::filter(new_df, sentence_wc > 0L)
}

out <- posts_sentences %>%
  group_by(element_id) %>%
  do(group_fun(., max.words=5L, regex="[.;:!] ?"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer that works on all sentences! However, I am looking to only split sentences where the word count is greater than a certain number (ex. 15) and leave the rest of the sentences the same as before. Any ideas of how to modify your answer to work like that?

Comment: Given my current answer, can I assume that each element in `grouped_df$sentence` is already a full sentence? So I don't have to merge them into one long character before deciding if they're too long?

Comment: Nevermind, I have updated my answer. You will need the `stringi` package.

Answer (score 1):

This solution first split the sentence by comma or period before a capital letter. Then split the sentence just by comma and period. Finally, if a sentence is still above a the limit words. the sentences is splited by each cappital leter.

```
posts_sentences <- data.frame("element_id" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), "sentence_id" = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3), 
                              "sentence" = c("You know, when I grew up, I grew up in a very religious family, I had the same sought of troubles people have, I was excelling in alot of ways, but because there was alot of trouble at home, we were always moving around", "Im at breaking point.I have no one to talk to about this and if I’m honest I think I’m too scared to tell anyone because if I do then it becomes real.I dont know what to do.", "I feel like I’m going to explode.", "I have so many thoughts and feelings inside and I don't know who to tell and I was going to tell my friend about it but I'm not sure.", "I keep saying omg!it's too much"), 
                              "sentence_wc" = c(60, 30, 7, 20, 7), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# To create an empty data frame to save the new elements

new_posts_sentences <- data.frame(element_id = as.numeric(),
                 sentence_id =as.numeric(), 
                 sentence = character(), 
                 sentence_wc = as.numeric(),  stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

limit_words <- 15 # 15 for this data set

countSentences <- 0

for (sentence in posts_sentences[,3]) {

        vector <- character()

        Velement_id <- posts_sentences$element_id[countSentences + 1]

        vector <- c(vector, sentence) #To create a vector with the sentences
        vector <- vector[!vector %in% ''] #remove empty elements from vector

        ## First we will separate the sentences that start with a uppercase after of a capital letter
        if(lengths(gregexpr("[A-z]\\W+", sentence)) > limit_words ){

                vector <- vector[!vector %in% sentence]

                split_points <- unlist(gregexpr("[:,:]\\s[A-Z]", sentence)) # To get the character position

                ## If a sentences is still over the limit words value. Let's split it for each comma or period
                sentences_1 <- substring(sentence, c(1, split_points + 2), c(split_points -1, nchar(sentence)))

                for(sentence in sentences_1){

                        vector <- c(vector, sentence)
                        vector <- vector[!vector %in% '']

                        if(lengths(gregexpr("[A-z]\\W+", sentence)) > limit_words){

                                vector <- vector[!vector %in% sentence]

                                split_points <- unlist(gregexpr("[:,:]|[:.:]", sentence))

                                sentences_2 <- substring(sentence, c(1, split_points + 1), c(split_points -1, nchar(sentence)))

                                ## If a sentence is still s still over the limit words value. Let's split it for each capital letter

                                for(sentence in sentences_2){

                                        vector <- c(vector, sentence)
                                        vector <- vector[!vector %in% '']

                                        if(lengths(gregexpr("[A-z]\\W+", sentence)) > limit_words){

                                                vector <- vector[!vector %in% sentence]

                                                split_points <- unlist(gregexpr("[A-Z]", sentence))

                                                sentences_3 <- substring(sentence,c(1, split_points), c(split_points -1, nchar(sentence)))

                                                vector <- c(vector, sentences_3)
                                                vector <- vector[!vector %in% '']

                                        }

                                }

                        }

                }

        }

        ## To make a data frame o each original sentence
        element_id <- rep(Velement_id, length(vector))
        sentence_id <- 1:length(vector)
        sentence_wc <- character()
        for (element in vector){sentence_wc <- c(sentence_wc, (lengths(gregexpr("[A-z]\\W+", element)))) }
        sentenceDataFrame <- data.frame(element_id, sentence_id, vector, sentence_wc)       

        ## To join it with the final dataframe
        new_posts_sentences <- rbind(new_posts_sentences, sentenceDataFrame)

        countSentences <- countSentences + 1

}
```

You get this data frame

```
print(new_posts_sentences)

   element_id sentence_id                                           vector sentence_wc
1           1           1                         You know, when I grew up           5
2           1           2             I grew up in a very religious family           7
3           1           3    I had the same sought of troubles people have           8
4           1           4                  I was excelling in alot of ways           6
5           1           5    but because there was alot of trouble at home           8
6           1           6                     we were always moving around           4
7           1           1                             Im at breaking point           3
8           1           2      I have no one to talk to about this and if           11
9           1           3                                      I’m honest            3
10          1           4                                         I think            2
11          1           5        I’m too scared to tell anyone because if            9
12          1           6                        I do then it becomes real           5
13          1           7                           I dont know what to do           5
14          2           1                I feel like I’m going to explode.           8
15          2           1 I have so many thoughts and feelings inside and            9
16          2           2                    I don't know who to tell and            8
17          2           3      I was going to tell my friend about it but           10
18          2           4                                     I'm not sure           3
19          2           1                  I keep saying omg!it's too much           7
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
library(utils)

check_and_split <- function(element_id, sentence_id, sentence, sentence_wc,
                             word_count, attmpt){

  methods <- c("\\.", ",\\s?(?=[I])", "and\\s?(?=[A-Z])")
  df <- data.frame(element_id=element_id,
             sentence_id=sentence_id,
             sentence=sentence,
             sentence_wc=sentence_wc,
             word_count=word_count,
             attmpt=attmpt,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    if(word_count<=15 | attmpt>=3){
      return(df) #early return
    } else{
     df %>% 
        tidyr::separate_rows(sentence, sep=methods[attmpt+1]) %>% 
        mutate(word_count=str_count(sentence,'\\w+'),
               attmpt = attmpt+1)
    }
}

posts_sentences %>% 
  mutate(word_count=str_count(sentence,'\\w+'),
         attmpt=0) %>%
  pmap_dfr(check_and_split) %>% 
  pmap_dfr(check_and_split) %>% 
  pmap_dfr(check_and_split)
```

Here, we create a helper function that takes a row (decomposed by element, as served by `purrr::pmap()`), we assemble it back into the dataframe, check if the word count is over 15 and number of attempts tried on the sentence before. Then we use `tidyr::separate_rows()` with separation token corresponding to the next attempt, update `word_count` and `number of attempts` and return the data frame.

I am applying the same function three times - this can be probably wrapped into a loop (lapply/purrr::map will not work since we need to update the sequentially update the dataframe).

In terms of regex tokens, first we are using literal `.`, then we are tracking comma and zero or more spaces, followed by "I". Note the positive lookahead syntax. Lastly we are trying "and" with, possibly, space, lookahead followed by capital letter.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the str_split() function from the stringr package (to split each text block according to your regex), followed by the unnest() function from the tidyr package.

```
sentences_split = posts_sentences %>%
  mutate(text_split=str_split(sentence, pattern = "\\.")) %>%
  unnest(text_split) %>%

  #Count number of words in text_split
  mutate(wc_split = str_count(text_split, "\\w+")) %>%

  filter(wc_split!=0) %>%

  #Split again if text_split column has >15 words
  mutate(text_split_again = ifelse(wc_split>15, str_split(text_split, pattern = ",\\sI"), text_split)) %>%
  unnest(text_split_again)
```